# Metric space is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

I was reading [Is this proof that all metric spaces are Hausdorff spaces correct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475403/is-this-proof-that-all-metric-spaces-are-hausdorff-spaces-correct) to see how the statement is proved, but I have a question. Is it possible to generalize that any ball in metric space is open? How do we know the "open set" in metric space? Is it a convention to say that topology of metric space is topology generated by every ball around every point? I can't think it right now but would there be any topology in metric space that some ball around some point is not open?

Comment: open balls are a base for the topology of a metric space

Comment: But maybe that's the one that needs to be proved as well using axioms. right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a metric space $(X,d)$, the topology *induced* by the metric $d$, i.e., the topology generated by the open balls:
$$
B(x,r)=\{y\in X\mid d(y,x)<r\}
$$
is called "metric topology" of $X$.

**By definition**, any open ball is an open set under this topology.

> but would there be any topology in metric space that some ball around some point is not open?

As a set, you can of course define other topology $\tau$ on $X$. An "open ball" of $(X,d)$ is then not necessarily an "open" set in $\tau$.